# How to FindGameObjectsWithTag then cast the array of GameObjects to an Array of Interfaces

Tags: unity

I have a few GameObjects that implement a common Interface: IsTree.
I need to call the function doTreeThing() on each of those IsTrees after getting a reference to each of them via FindGameObjectsWithTag("tree").

This line complains that it cannot implicitly convert from GameObject[] to IsTree[]

```
IsTree[] trees = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("tree");
```

So then I tried to leave the GameObject[] an iterate over it to convert each individual object inside to an IsTree.

```
GameObject[] trees = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("tree");
        foreach (GameObject tree in trees) {
            IsTree isTree = (IsTree)tree;
            isTree.doTreeThing();
        }
```

But this complains that it also cannot convert GameObject to IsTree.

Then I got a little desperate and tried to make my IsTree into a GameObject.

```
public class IsTree : GameObject {
    public System.DateTime getAge(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

GameObject is a sealed type. (I don't really know what that means besides that this does not work)

So how do I get this array of GameObjects into an array of SomeInterface?

Comment: Did you consider FindObjectsOfType<Tree> instead?

Answer (score 1):

GameObjects are not their components. They are containers *for* their components. So once you have the GameObject, you have to get the component from it, rather than just assume it *is* it.

```
GameObject[] trees = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("tree");
foreach (GameObject tree in trees) {
    IsTree isTree = tree.GetComponent<IsTree>();
    isTree.doTreeThing();
}
```

DMGregory’s suggestion should also work:

```
IsTree[] trees = GameObject.FindGameObjectsOfType<IsTree>();
```